# How can I find the box dimension of $\{ \frac{1}{n^m}\mid n=1,2,3,\ldots \}$ for a fixed $m$?

Tags: measure-theory, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

I recently learned of the concept of box dimension (also called the [Minkowski-Bouligand dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension)) as a way of measuring the dimension of a set (with use in describing the non-integer dimensions of some fractals) - it's sometimes compared to the [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) and in some cases can be simpler to calculate. The box-dimension of a set $S$ contained in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space considers the occupancy of a grid of equal size boxes of lateral dimension $\epsilon$. In particular, calling the number of boxes containing at least one element of $S$ $N(\epsilon)$, we have $$B(S) = \lim_{\epsilon \to0} \frac{\log(N(\epsilon))}{\log(\frac{1}{\epsilon})}$$

For example, the box dimension of the set $S={1, 1/2, 1/3,..}$ on the real line (i.e. $\frac{1}{n}$ for integers $n>0$) is $1/2$, as noted in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576722/prove-that-the-box-dimension-of-0-1-frac12-frac13-is-frac).

---

What is the box dimension of $\{ \frac{1}{n^m}\mid n=1,2,3,\ldots \}$?

---

Here are my thoughts. I believe that in general, $\{ \frac{1}{n^m}\mid n=1,2,3,\ldots \}$ has box dimension $\frac{1}{m+1}$ for positive $m$.

For my question asking about the infinite union of all of these sets, please see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656613/how-can-i-find-the-box-dimension-of-the-infinite-union-cup-m-1-infty-fr).

Comment: What's the box dimension of $\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \left\{ 1/n + f(m) : n > 0 \right\}$ for some bounded decreasing $f$, like $f(m)=e^{-m}$? If that's still 1/2 maybe that's a useful hint

Comment: This set is equal to the set $\{ 1/n : n=1,2,3,... \}$ because $n^m$ is a positive integer for every $n,m \ge 1$, so yes, the box counting dimension is indeed 1/2.

Comment: @LukasGeyer That is quite the oversight on my part :). I'm going to spin off this question into a couple different questions re: Sarvesh's recommendation below, since there was a little confusion over what I was asking. I'll update my question with links to the others, and I would appreciate if you make your comment an answer once I provide the link.

Comment: @LukasGeyer I'd be happy if you made your comment an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656613/how-can-i-find-the-box-dimension-of-the-infinite-union-cup-m-1-infty-fr. I'll try designing a less pathological question as a third question, maybe in the vein of Alex K's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is easier than I thought. Fix $m \geq 1$.

The idea is the same as in the set $\{\frac 1n : n \geq 1\}$. Covering $0$ by an interval is going to take away all but finitely many points, and all we're left to do is argue about how these points are going to be covered.

Namely, let $\delta > 0$ be given as the diameter of the intervals we need to cover the set $\{\frac 1{k^m} : k \geq 1\}$ with. We must find $K(\delta)$ such that it should be impossible that both $\frac{1}{k^m}$ and $\frac 1{l^m}$ can lie together in any set of length $\delta$ for all $k,l \leq K$. In the case $m=1$, we found that $K(\delta)$ was like $\frac 1{\delta^2}$ asymptotically.

This is the same as insisting that $\inf_{k,l \leq K} |\frac{1}{k^m} - \frac 1{l^m}| > \delta$. However , the infimum on the RHS is attained precisely when $k=K-1,l=K$. In other words, we want $K(\delta)$ such that $$
\frac{1}{(K(\delta)-1)^{m}} - \frac 1{K(\delta)^m} > \delta \geq \frac{1}{K(\delta)^m} - \frac 1{(K(\delta)+1)^m} \tag{0} \label{0}
$$
Once such a $K(\delta)$ is found, it becomes clear that covering the set $\{\frac 1{k^m} : k \leq K(\delta)\}$ requires at least $K(\delta)$ boxes of diameter $\delta$.

On the other hand, we can also exhibit a covering of comparable size. To do this, consider the same $K(\delta)$ as above and cover each of the numbers $\frac 1{k^m}, k \leq K(\delta)$ with one interval of size $\delta$. Then, all the remaining elements lie inside the interval $[0,\frac{1}{(K(\delta)+1)^m}]$, which means that we require at most $\lfloor\frac{1/(K(\delta)+1)^m}{\delta}\rfloor+1$ intervals to cover this set.

In other words, we have shown that if $N(\delta)$ is the smallest number of intervals of size $\delta$ required to cover the set $\{\frac 1{k^m}, k \geq 1\}$ then $$
K(\delta) \leq N(\delta) \leq K(\delta) + \lfloor\frac{1/(K(\delta)+1)^m}{\delta}\rfloor+1 \tag{1} \label{1}
$$

All we require now are bounds on $K(\delta)$. We proceed somewhat heuristically at this point, as I plan to leave a proper, rigorous proof sketch at the end.

One easily sees by taking the common denominator that $$
\frac{1}{(K(\delta)-1)^{m}} - \frac 1{K(\delta)^m} > \delta \implies \frac{p(K(\delta))}{q(K(\delta))}>\delta
$$
where $p(x),q(x)$ are polynomials of degree $m-1,2m$ respectively in $x$. The leading coefficient of $p$ is $m$ and of $q$ is $1$, so limit heuristics tell us that we can treat this "like" $\frac{mK(\delta)^{m-1}}{K(\delta)^{2m}} > \delta$, which simplifies to $K(\delta) > \left(\frac{\delta}{m}\right)^{\frac{-1}{m+1}}$ up to a constant, but $m$ itself is a constant as $\delta \to 0$, hence we may say that $K(\delta) > \delta^{-1/(m+1)}$ up to a constant. Similarly , the other inequality tells you that $K(\delta) \approx \delta^{-1/(m+1)}$ as $\delta \to 0$, up to constants.

If we continue with the heuristics, then $$
\lfloor\frac{1/(K(\delta)+1)^m}{\delta}\rfloor \approx \frac{1/(K(\delta)+1)^m}{\delta} \approx \frac{1}{\delta \times \delta^{-m/(m+1)}} \approx \delta^{-\frac 1{m+1}}
$$

All in all, it becomes clear from \eqref{1} that $N(\delta) \approx \frac 1{\delta}^{\frac 1{m+1}}$ as $\delta \to 0$. The answer is $\frac 1{m+1}$.

---

Of course, I was *not rigorous in parts*. Therefore, I will provide below, a proof sketch that is completely rigorous.

- Prove that $K(\delta) \to +\infty$ as $\delta \to 0$.
- Multiply all sides of \eqref{0} by the quantity $K(\delta)^{m+1}$. This leads to $$
  \frac{K(\delta)^{m+1}}{(K(\delta)-1)^m}-K(\delta) \geq \delta K(\delta)^{m+1} \geq K(\delta)-\frac{K(\delta)^{m+1}}{(K(\delta)+1)^m} \tag{2} \label{2}
  $$
- Observe that $$
  \frac{K(\delta)^{m+1}}{(K(\delta)-1)^m}-K(\delta) = \frac{mK(\delta)^m + q(K(\delta))}{(K(\delta)-1)^m}
  $$
  where $q$ has degree at most $m-1$. Dividing top and bottom by $K(\delta)^m$, letting $\delta \to 0$ and recalling our first bullet point, it is clear that the LHS of \eqref{2} goes to $m$ as $\delta \to 0$. Something similar applies to the RHS of \eqref{2}, which also goes to $m$ as $\delta \to 0$.
- In particular, $\delta K(\delta)^{m+1} \to m$ as $\delta \to 0$ by the squeeze theorem. Taking inverses, $\frac 1{\delta K(\delta)^{m+1}} \to \frac 1m$ as $\delta \to 0$.
- Using that particular limit and a ratio comparison + squeeze argument, show that $$
  \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{\frac 1{\delta K(\delta)^{m+1}}}{\frac 1{K(\delta)}\left(\lfloor\frac{1/(K(\delta)+1)^m}{\delta}\rfloor+1\right)} = 1
  $$
  Therefore, $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac 1{K(\delta)}\left(\lfloor\frac{1/(K(\delta)+1)^m}{\delta}\rfloor+1\right) = \frac 1m$. By the definition of limit, for some fixed $M>\frac 1m$ and all $\delta>0$ small enough, $\left(\lfloor\frac{1/(K(\delta)+1)^m}{\delta}\rfloor+1\right)<MK(\delta)$.
- Plugging this into \eqref{1}, we get $K(\delta)\leq N(\delta) \leq K(\delta)(M+1)$, and taking logarithms and diving by $\log \frac 1\delta$ gives $$
  \frac{\log K(\delta)}{\log\frac 1 \delta} \leq \frac{\log N(\delta)}{\log \frac 1{\delta}} \leq \frac{\log K(\delta)}{\log\frac 1 \delta}+\frac{\log(M+1)}{\log \frac 1 \delta}
  $$
  as $\delta K(\delta)^{m+1} \to m$, taking logarithms and rearranging gives that the right and left hand side of the above equation go to $\frac 1{m+1}$ as $\delta \to 0$. It follows that $\frac{\log N(\delta)}{\log \frac 1{\delta}} \to \frac 1{m+1}$ as $\delta \to 0$, completing the proof.

---

I am not fully sure about how much this will work when the structure of the set is perturbed too much. However, there is a general strategy when your set consists of a monotonic sequence $a_n$ which is decreasing to $0$. (and by translation to more general situations).

If your set $S = \{a_n : n \geq 1\}$ where $a_n$ is strictly decreasing (no point of counting the same element twice), $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then we can do the same thing. Given $\delta>0$, let $K(\delta)$ be the smallest positive number satisfying $$
\inf_{k,l \leq K(\delta)} |a_k - a_l| \geq \delta
$$
Then, to cover the elements $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{K(\delta)}$ one requires at least $K(\delta)$ elements. Now, the rest of the elements are contained in $[0,a_{K(\delta)+1}]$, therefore we can use $\lfloor\frac{a_{K(\delta)+1}}{\delta}\rfloor+1$ intervals to cover these up. We land up with the bound $$
K(\delta) \leq N(\delta) \leq K(\delta) +\lfloor\frac{a_{K(\delta)+1}}{\delta}\rfloor+1
$$

Now, suppose it happens that $\lfloor\frac{a_{K(\delta)+1}}{\delta}\rfloor+1 \leq MK(\delta)$ for some constant $M>0$ and small enough $\delta>0$. We can easily see that the box-counting dimension equals $\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{\log K(\delta)}{\log \frac 1{\delta}}$ in this case, whenever that limit exists.

What happens if this *does not* occur? That can only happen when the $a_n$ continue to be really spaced "far apart" as $n \to \infty$, so that the brute force covering by adjacent intervals of size $\delta$ becomes inefficient and we have to account for gaps in the $a_n$ which could be abnormally large. This is possible in a fractal-like situation, but in a situation where there is a lot of monotonicity (for example, I think insisting that $a_{n} - a_{n+1}$ is a decreasing sequence as well should be good enough) it shouldn't occur.

I am not sure what can be said about infinitely many unions of sets and the box-counting dimension, but in this particular scenario it is clear that the box-dimension should be computable in a large number of situations.

Comment: I worry my question was somewhat unclear. I'm looking for the box dimension of the single set that contains $\frac{1}{n^m}$ for $n,m$ integers $>1$, not the box dimensions of each of the sets $\{ \frac{1}{n^m}|n=1,2,3,... \}$ for each $m=1,2,3,...$. I think you've written a really nice answer for the latter question, and it would be nice to preserve this answer. What do you recommend? Maybe you could try the "answer your own question" option and ask and answer this latter question? I want to preserve this answer and have it properly recognized.

Comment: Also, please let me know if any edits to my question could make my question more clear.

Comment: @user196574 I'm sorry I misinterpreted your question. Interestingly enough, if I may offer, I encourage you to look at the last section of this answer, because the set $\{\frac 1{n^m} , n , m \in \mathbb N\}$ can be rearranged into a (strictly, by removing duplicate terms) decreasing sequence. You can use that to provide *upper and lower bounds* for the dimension of the set you seek. Perhaps they might match. As it stands, I believe that for your set, the box dimension is equal to $\frac 12$. See if you can get the lower bound to match? Also , thank you for your response!

Comment: @user196574 For your question, I would suggest reverting it to the original question of the Hausdorff dimension of $\{\frac {1}{n^m}, n = 1,2,3,\ldots\}$ for *fixed* $m$. However, I will work hard on trying to see if I can extend the logic to the set of *all* powers , which is your current question. Even if I do that, I would suggest rolling back the question.

Comment: Done! I made the spinoff question (my original aim for the question) at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656613/how-can-i-find-the-box-dimension-of-the-infinite-union-cup-m-1-infty-fr; Lukas's comment above clicked with me, so I'll probably accept his answer to that question if he posts one.

Comment: @user196574 Thank you very much, and I hope that many can benefit from your excellent question and thought process.