# Box dimension of a perturbed set in the interval $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

I've asked a [couple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651034/how-can-i-find-the-box-dimension-of-frac1nm-mid-n-1-2-3-ldots-for) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656613/how-can-i-find-the-box-dimension-of-the-infinite-union-cup-m-1-infty-fr) about box dimensions (also called the [Minkowski-Bouligand dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension)) recently. My main goal is to better understand the box dimension of discrete sets of points within the interval $[0,1]$; in particular, I'm interested in ways to compute the box dimension quickly. My hope is that the following question would give me a useful tool in computing box dimensions.

Suppose that we have two sets of points $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ taking values between $0$ and $1$. I imagine that $f$ and $g$ are monotonically decreasing functions with a non-negative second derivative, like $\frac{1}{n}$ and $e^{-n}$. Suppose that the box dimensions of these sets of points satisfy $B(\{f(n): n=1,2,3...\}) \geq B(\{g(n): n=1,2,3...\})$. Are we guaranteed that $B(\{f(n)+g(n): n=1,2,3...\}) = B(\{f(n): n=1,2,3...\})$? That is, if we "perturb" the points of $f(n)$ by $g(n)$, do we keep the same box dimension?

---

This question was motivated by a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651034/how-can-i-find-the-box-dimension-of-frac1nm-mid-n-1-2-3-ldots-for#comment9830988_4651034) by Alex K - if it turns out that we are guaranteed the equality above, this could ease the computation of the box dimension of weakly perturbed sets of points.